# Editing a shared document in Word from a link in OneNote

Tags: 2010

I hope this is the right SE for this question; I believe the mismatch between expectations and actual behavior comes from my lack of understanding the Sharepoint component in this use case.

I have a nicely formatted page in a OneNote notebook which contains a sort of table of contents for a series of Word documents. The actual documents are stored in a SharePoint library, and I use the hyperlinks in my OneNote notebook to open them on the fly when I need to look something up. However, they always open in Read-only mode. If I navigate to the actual library and click the document name, I get a small popup asking if I want read-only or edit mode. The hyperlinks are in the format "http: //[sharepoint site]/[directory path]/[Library]/[Filename].docx". (space added to break link)

Is there some way I can make these files open in edit mode?